# Exclude jquery from maven-javadoc-plugin

Tags: maven-javadoc-plugin

Trying to generate javadoc without jquery  using "maven-javadoc-plugin", where as it will include jquery if the source is compiled with JDK 11 and above, where as if the same is compiled with JDK 8 then it won't.

Tried adding "doclint" (none) and "additionalparam" (-Xdoclint:none), but that didn't helped.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <quiet>true</quiet>
                    <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                    <doclint>none</doclint>
                    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Solution :

```
<configuration>
   ...
   <noindex>true</noindex>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

by adding "true" avoids jquery to be part of javadoc.